# What is a devel-release?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

There are a lot of people that have problems upgrading to 13.04... now every time they are told to put this in the Terminal: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. Now I've been wondering what the `-d` stands for.

In the man pages they speak of a devel release. Can someone explain to me what a devel release is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not devil, but devel. It's short for development :)

Comment: Ubuntu does a lot of development on the Ubuntu OS, and you can upgrade your OS to that release by running the above command. You can find more info at http://www.ubuntu.com/testing, and I'd advise you don't run that command as your OS will be quite unstable. ;)

Comment: ohhh yeah I'll read more carefully next time... :D Thanks now i can rest in peace :P

Comment: Hmm, since in the question the "devil" was corrected to "devel", this answer doesn't make much sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It says quite clearly **devel-release**, not **devil**. And what the command does is to upgrade your current release to the next development release.

> ```
>  -d, --devel-release
>
>  Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible
> ```

[Ubuntu Wiki.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html)